# std::thread, thowing an exception in thread causes abort error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I have been experimenting with std:thread. I am using a binary expression tree for the standard arithmetic operations. I am creating a thread to perform the calculations and want to check for divide by zero. When the thread is started with `std::async`, the exception is thrown from the worker thread and caught just fine in the main thread.  When I  start the thread with std::thread, when the exception is thrown, I get a run-time error, `abort()`.  Any insights as to why it works with `std::async but not`std::thread`?

```
// Declaration in the Expression.h file
public:
    static long double __stdcall ThreadStaticEntryPoint(void * pThis);


long double __stdcall Expression::ThreadStaticEntryPoint(void * pThis)
{
    long double calc;

    Expression* pthrdThis = (Expression*)pThis;
    calc = pthrdThis->Calculate();

    return calc;
}

case 6:
    try {
    // Below works when encountering divide by zero.
    // The thrown exception is caught correctly  
    // Launch thread using the this pointer

        std::future<long double> fu = std::async(std::launch::async,
            ThreadStaticEntryPoint, this);
        calc = fu.get();

        // When Creating a thread as below and I throw a divide by zero 
    // exception I get an error in visual C++. Below does not work:

        //std::thread t1(&Expresson::Calculate, this);
        //t1.join();

        // Below works fine also
        //calc = Calculate();
    }
    catch (runtime_error &r)
    {
            ShowMessage("LoadMenu() Caught exception calling Calculate()");
            ShowMessage(r.what());
    }
    catch (...) {
            ShowMessage("Exception caught");
        }

long double Expresson::Calculate()
{
    Expression *e;
    long double calc = 0;

    e = rep->GetExpression();
    if (e == NULL)
    {
        ShowMessage("Main Expression " + to_string(rep->GetMainExpIndex()) + " is NULL. ");
        return 0;
    }

    calc = e->Calculate()

    return calc;
}

//************************************************************
// Calculate - Calculates Lval / Rval, returns result
//************************************************************
long double Divide::Calculate()
{
    Expression* lop = this->getLOperand();
    Expression* rop = this->getROperand();
    long double Lval = 0, Rval = 0;
    long double result = 0;

    if (lop == NULL || rop == NULL)
        return result;

    Lval = lop->Calculate();
    Rval = rop->Calculate();
    //result = divides<long double>()(Lval, Rval);
    // The throw error below causes the error
    if (Rval == 0)
        throw runtime_error("DivExp::Calculate() - Divide by zero exception occured. Rval = 0");

    result = Lval / Rval;

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to "work"? (I put "work" in quotes because this program works fine; it just doesn't do what you expect)

Comment: It does exactly what expect for all cases. It's only when I throw an exception, when starting the thread with std::thread, that I get a runtime abort(). If the thread is started with std::async and I throw an exception, it is caught in the main thread as I expect. WHy do you say it doesn't do what I expect ?

Comment: Because the case where you throw an exception is still a case, and it doesn't do what you expect in that case...

Comment: Okay, you are right about that. I cannot seem to find a solution, so I was thinking that I am overlooking something. BTW, the std::async thread runs correctly without aborting even when I call the calculate function as I do with std::thread (i.e std::future<long double> fu = std::async(std::launch::async, &Expression::Calculate, this);
calc = fu.get();

Answer (score 6):

That is the expected behavior:

See the [std::thread documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

> Threads begin execution immediately upon construction of the associated thread object (pending any OS scheduling delays), starting at the top-level function provided as a constructor argument. The return value of the top-level function is ignored and **if it terminates by throwing an exception, std::terminate is called**.

See the [std::async documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

> then async executes the function f on a new thread of execution (with all thread-locals initialized) as if spawned by std::thread(f, args...), **except that if the function f returns a value or throws an exception, it is stored in the shared state** accessible through the std::future that async returns to the caller.

Comment: You are exactly correct.  I guess it always helps to read the "instructions" before assembly. I always have had a couple of screws left over, or been missing one, before I finally read the instructions.  Thanks much.